# Custom image buttons in android navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to add custom buttons to my android navigation drawer, which currently has the menu with items that have checkable boxes. I would like to replace them with image buttons that I can place into the drawer without an order.

This is my activity main xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sliderbackground"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Image button in the header
Go to nav_header_home layout and add Image Button to it :

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgBtn"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

reference it in your main.java

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        imagebtn = (ImageButton) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
```

Comment: Thx but I solved it through wrapping the navigation view with a relativelayout then placing a image button into it and elevating the button.